# How can I access the controls on my ASP.NET page from a class within the solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, textbox, reference

Basically I am not using a MasterPage and I just have a project with a Default.aspx with a few labels, textBoxes etc. I've spent several hours looking for a solution and I have found one, but something in my head still bugs me, that I didn't do it the way I wanted to.

I have no troubles accessing them and setting their properties from the PageLoad.

But I made a class, just like the code snippet below, and it throws me an **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"**. And I cannot seem to figure out what I am missing.

```
   class Functions 
    {
       public static void myMethod()
       {
            WebForm1 mainForm = new WebForm1();
            mainForm.myTextBox.Text = "Something.";
       }
    }
```

I managed to do with like this:

```
   class Functions 
    {
       public static void myMethod()
       {
           System.Web.UI.Page myMainForm;
           myMainForm = (System.Web.UI.Page)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler;
           TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)myMainForm.FindControl("myTextBox");
       }
    }
```

But it's not about just doing it, it's about **learning where I am wrong** as I cannot figure it out and I want a simpler way to do it, considering I am very new to ASP.NET. Normally when I am coding basic applications in WinForms - I don't have problems accessing different forms.

And I don't like doing a **FindControl()** for every control I am trying to access. If there is a *simple and yet effective* workaround I would love to hear it.

Thank you in advance.

**Edit**: I've made this example aside from my project, but it's the idea I am trying to accomplish. There might be some small errors in the code snippets, please excuse me.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You're going about this all wrong.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do either.

Comment: I am just trying to access the controls from within a method, as I explained. The whole project and its idea is bigger but it's irrelevant to what I am asking.

Comment: Excuse me if I am making this hard for you guys, obviously too new to explain things properly.

Comment: You're too new to understand that it's an extremely bad idea to have a method in another class reference controls from your page. Pages are classes. Your method is in another class. You're talking about exposing the private implementation of one class into another. Very Bad Idea.

Comment: But what are you actually trying to do? If you're just trying to access, say, the "`Text`" property of some text boxes, then just pass `txtMyTextBox.Text` to the method. If you need to access the entire control (still not a great idea), then pass the entire `txtMyTextBox` to the method.

Comment: I cannot pass anything to the method, only managed to pass the control through the snippet in the second part of my message. Obviously I don't know how to pass it, and that's what I am asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the code-behind files for this.  Don't tightly couple business logic classes to your user interface.

WebForm1.aspx should have WebForm1.aspx.cs if using c# or WebForm.aspx.vb if using vb, so if you have a TextBox control on WebForm1.aspx, you should be able to access it in the code-behind file (WebForm1.aspx.cs or WebForm1.aspx.vb)

```
public class Validate
{
    public bool IsEmail(string email)
    {
        //return false if invalid e-mail or true if valid
    }
}
```

Then in your WebForm.aspx.cs, you can call

```
 Validate validate = new Validate();
 bool isValidEmail = validate.IsEmail(txtEmail.Text);
```

Where txtEmail is the control.  You can make the Validate class static, so you can just do:

```
 bool isvalidEmail = Validate.IsEmail(txtEmail.Text);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am asking, I cannot access it, those are code snippets from my code-behind and this is in the Default.aspx.cs

I can access the textBoxes or Labels only if I write in the "Page_Load" section. If I make a class and a method inside it, and I type for example textBox1.Text, it won't recognize it as an existing control.

Comment: @Synthel, you are going about it all wrong like others said then.  Separate your concerns.  Keep bll or dal classes outside of your code-behind files.

Comment: @Xaisoft So add them as separate items to the solution, is what you are suggesting rather than putting them below the Page_Load?

Comment: @Synthel, yes that is what I am suggesting. For example, you might have a class that contains methods to Validate the input of your controls, so you could create a Validate.cs class with Validation methods and then use the methods of Validate.cs to operate on your controls.  I will give an example.

Comment: @Synthel, remember this also, if you put classes inside your code-behind files, you lose the capability of reuse.  That means that if you had a class that had common functionality among many controls, are you going to copy the class into each Webform or have a single class that you can access from anywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot, off to my project to experiment with what I've read. I am new to the site so I cannot vote any answers useful yet, but this is one of them.

Comment: @Synthel, no problem and good luck.  If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask.  Just be patient and you will begin to understand :)

Comment: Hopefully, I will. Slow and steady.

Answer (score 2):

Controls on a page get created when processed by the asp.net system. They do not get created just by calling a constructor of the page class. This means that you cannot do what you originally tried - non of the controls will be there. The second version (FindControl) worked because you are using the page which got created properly by asp.net, by accessing HttpContext.Current.Handler.

As others have pointed out, it looks like you are trying to do something the wrong way. Since you say you are new to asp.net, maybe someone here can provide some guidance if you will explain what you need to accomplish (in a functional sense, not in a technical sense)

I should also point out that, even if you were successful in creating the page with a simple constructor call, it would be a new instance of the page, and not the one that your user posted back to you.

Comment: It was nice to know why it worked, but it's not nice to learn I am totally wrong about the way I do it. If I try to explain the whole concept I will probably just piss off some people even more.

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is declare your control in the designer or in the code behind. Say, myTextBox is your declared textbox. If you'd like to modify this text box's text you should create a property like so

```
public string MyTextBoxText
{
   get
   {
      return MyTextBox.Text;
   }
   set
   {
      MyTextBox.Text = value;
   }
}
```

Sorry for the formatting,... I keep trying to ctrl+K+D but it's not working ;).

Then you should access the properties and manipulate them through the properties. As others have stated, it'll help to know why you're trying to modify this from other classes, or how you're attempting to go about it. If you want to modify the text box through, say, a presenter, this property will be exposed and can be manipulated while shielding the properties you don't want changed from being exposed (which wouldn't be the case if you exposed the entire control)

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I will try it now and see how it goes. Also thanks for staying friendly to the beginners unlike some others.

Comment: I have a question, is this considered a good practice. I mean, further on if I am trying to achieve similar results I should rather just pass the needed property rather than passing the whole control?

Comment: Yes, definitely, unless there is a specific reason you need the entire control you should only expose the properties that you need to modify (usually only one per control, such as .Text, .Checked, etc)

Comment: I've just tried to expose such property in the designer.cs file of the main page, however, I am still unable to access the exposed property in a method. 

My idea was to make an Initialize() and possibly several other methods that are called when the page loads. For example on of those methods will put a name in the TextBox based on a LinqToSql query. However, I cannot call the TextBox.Text property even though I exposed it like you suggested. It still throws a null reference.

What am I missing again?

Answer (score 1):

Passing or accessing controls like this is very wrong. Rather send the data you need to that method via method arguments, or initialize the Functions class with necessary data (for instance: control.Text or something) before calling your methods. What you are also trying to do here is typical Functional programming, without any OOP code. Try to find a good book about OOP and read it first, it will make everything easier for you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I will read further on this. But I believe I've explained things very wrong and everyone misunderstood me.

Answer (score 1):

Since sometimes you just need an answer and need it now, try this:

```
class Functions 
{
   public static void myMethod()
   {
       WebForm1 myMainForm;
       myMainForm = (WebForm1)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler;
       TextBox myTextBox = myMainForm.myTextBox;
   }
}
```

The trick is to cast the Handler to the type of the Page, not to the base Page class.  Doing this you can access your Page strongly without using FindControl.  Since this Functions class can't access the protected properties on the Page, you'll also need to expose their data using public properties as Mike M. suggested.

Comment: Thank you Kevin, I will try this if I don't figure out how to do it properly. Now I am a bit worried that I am doing it wrong logically so trying to figure out the proper way to do it rather than learning it the wrong way.

Comment: Thanks again Kevin, you and Mike and Xisoft have been very useful but I am not sure how to vote up all of you at once. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the STATIC keyword from your method.  Then you will be able to reference the controls directly. :)